# how stop loop slideshow in android

Tags: java, android, handler

I need to stop loop. I have four pics: so after that slide go to 4 pic I need to stop slide.

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static ViewPager mPager;
    private static int currentPage = 0;
    private static int NUM_PAGES = 0;
     private static final Integer[] IMAGES= {R.drawable.one,R.drawable.two,R.drawable.three,R.drawable.five};
private ArrayList<Integer> ImagesArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        for(int i=0;i<IMAGES.length;i++)
            ImagesArray.add(IMAGES[i]);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mPager.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(MainActivity.this,ImagesArray));

        CirclePageIndicator indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)
                findViewById(R.id.indicator);

        indicator.setViewPager(mPager);

        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        indicator.setRadius(5 * density);

        NUM_PAGES =IMAGES.length;

        // Auto start of viewpager
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };
        Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 3000, 3000);

        // Pager listener over indicator
        indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                currentPage = position;

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, so you've told us what you're trying to do and shown us 85 lines of code - what's the difference between those two? What happens now that you don't want to happen, or vice versa?

Comment: now pics scroll in loop...always sliding...but i not need loop...all pics must slide only one time

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't a very clear comment. Please edit your question to state more clearly what the problem is - and ideally reduce your code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the code but I think the problem is here:

```
final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };
```

Whenever it reaches the end it checks for this condition `(currentPage == NUM_PAGES)` and it restarts from 0.

If you want to just stop when it reaches the end you should use this:

```
final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (currentPage < NUM_PAGES) {
                         mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
                    }
                }
            };
```

It should stop when `currentPage == NUM_PAGES`

Comment: @alex no problem, glad I could help! :)